# How to call separate function from def __init__(self):

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am relatively new to OOP and I have a problem with my code. In an attempt to arrange my code, I would like to save functions in separate files (here `menu.py`) and then initialize them through `def __init__(self):` in `class` (file name `app.py`) (better than trying to understand my weird description is to look directly on my code ☻). It returns `AttributeError` and I have no clue how to repair it. Can anyone help me please? (P.S. if you understand what I am trying to do and you know better way how to do that, please tell me ☻)

```
app.py
```

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

from menu import Menu

class App(Menu):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        ...
        self.Menu_Bar()
        ...
        self.root.mainloop()
```

```
menu.py
```

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Menu():
    def Menu_Bar(self):
        self.menuBar = Menu(self.root)
        self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu = self.fileMenu)
        ...
        self.root.config(menu = self.menuBar)
```

```
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'Menu_Bar'
```

Comment: You aren't just doing OO your are doing inheritance.To solve your issue google inheritance in python. That being said you should probably just make a menu class member instead of doing inheritence.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: my apologies. I didn't read your comment close enough. I'll remove my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but unfortunately I do not get it yet. Can you give me another hint please?